# Multiple stores and multiple admins with different roles

Tags: magento

I have no doubt magento can handle multiple stores, but I was wondering if each stores can handle with such specific user wherein they can access their catalog, sales, inventory, etc like administrator, but limited only on their specific store.

Here's my sample representation:

```
Magento website:
->Store Categories
    -->Store1
          --->Product Categories
                 ----->Products
          --->Store Owner  -------- Who can logged in the backend to see all their products, sales, inventory, etc.. Only
                                                                                 access their  store.

   -->Store2
          --->Product Categories
                 ----->Products
          --->Store Owner2   ------ Who can logged in the backend to see all their products, sales, inventory, etc.. Only
                                                                                      access their  store.
```

Answer (score 3):

No, Magento is not built to allow different vendors to have access only to their information. I believe that Enterprise tries to add some of this functionality, but do not rely on the system keeping everything separate.

Notably, even if the products can be hacked, there is no such system of permissions for attributes, or attribute sets. If one owner deletes an attribute set, the store for the other owner will be affected. Similarly, the category manager has the same issue. Order management in the backend is in the same place.

Maybe not the answer you wanted, but hopefully that helps.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

Not at the Community Edition. 
The Enterprise Edition allows you to set that kind of roles.